# 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.'

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemove.Click
    lstOrder.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrder.SelectedIndex)
    If lstOrder.Items.Count < 5 Then
        btnAdd.Visible = True
    End If
    **If CInt(lstOrder.Text.Substring(0, 1)) <= 7 Then**
        regcount = regcount - 1
    Else
        gmtcount = gmtcount - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Having errors on the bolded line, it prevents me removing an item from my listbox saying 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.' no idea what this means would appreciate it if someone could help me out here. :)

Comment: You have just removed the selected item. `lstOrder.Text` will be an empty string. You need to debug your code.

Comment: Yes, stop whatever you're currently doing and learn how to debug.  Once you've done that, you'll be able to diagnose issues like this yourself because you'll be able to see exactly what each line of code is doing as it's doing it.  There's lots of information around but you might start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to access an empty string and take position 0 until position 1 which doesn't exist.

The reason it is empty is because you removed the SelectedItem in the first line.

However, for future reference, you should structure your if statement this way to prevent such an error:

```
If **lstOrder.Text.Length >= 1 AndAlso** CInt(lstOrder.Text.Substring(0, 1)) <= 7 Then**
    regcount = regcount - 1
Else
    gmtcount = gmtcount - 1
End If
```

Please note the "AndAlso" which short-circuits your logic if the first part isn't true. If you only put "And" it will try to check the logic in the second part of your logic (the CInt(lstOrder.Text)....) and fail.